# How to calculate negative log-likelihoog on MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, mnist

The following table

[image: NLL evaluations on MNIST test set.]

is from the [Professor Forcing: A New Algorithm for Training Recurrent Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09038.pdf) paper. But I couldn't find their code to calculate NLL. I would like to ask if it is simply the binary cross-entropy. Can I calculate it by using Tensorflow [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) function?

In Professor Forcing paper, the evaluation result with teacher forcing is not presented. I trained a straightforward LSTM and achieved an NLL of 80.394. My last question is how likely to get ~80 or ~70?

More specifically, I am trying to generate MNIST images pixel by pixel. My model makes a binary prediction for every pixel, which can take values of 0 and 1. The dimension of both logits and labels are `[batch_size, 28*28, 1]`, where 28 is the height and width of an MNIST image.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the negative log-likelihood is the log loss, or (binary) cross-entropy for (binary) classification problems, but since MNIST is a multi-class problem, here we talk about the *categorical* cross-entropy. It is usually preferred because, since log-likelihood itself is negative, its negative will be a positive number; from the scikit-learn docs of [`log_loss`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) (emphasis added):

> Log loss, aka logistic loss or cross-entropy loss.
>
> This is the loss function used in (multinomial) logistic regression
>   and extensions of it such as neural networks, defined as the **negative
>   log-likelihood** of the true labels given a probabilistic classifier’s
>   predictions. The log loss is only defined for two or more labels. For
>   a single sample with true label yt in {0,1} and estimated probability
>   yp that yt = 1, the log loss is
>
> ```
> -log P(yt|yp) = -(yt log(yp) + (1 - yt) log(1 - yp))
> ```

Not quite sure how you can do this with Tensorflow; here is a way to do it with Keras (to keep the code short & concise, I am building upon the [Keras MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py), run for only 2 epochs here, since we are only interested in getting our `y_pred` & demonstrating the procedure):

First of all, here is the categorical cross-entropy loss result as reported by Keras for the *test* set:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
# Test loss: 0.05165324027412571
# Test accuracy: 0.9834
```

Let's now see how we can get this loss result "manually", in case we have our predictions `y_pred` and true labels `y_test` irrespectively of any specific model used; notice only that the procedure is applicable when both our predictions and true labels are one-hot encoded, i.e.:

```
y_pred[0]
# array([2.4637930e-07, 1.0927782e-07, 1.0026793e-06, 7.6613435e-07,
#        4.1209915e-09, 1.4566888e-08, 2.3195759e-10, 9.9999702e-01,
#        4.9344425e-08, 8.6051602e-07], dtype=float32)
y_test[0]
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.])
```

Here is the precedure:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

y_test = y_test.astype('float32') # necessary here, since y_pred comes in this type - check in your case with y_test.dtype and y_pred.dtype
y_test = K.constant(y_test)
y_pred = K.constant(y_pred)

g = K.categorical_crossentropy(target=y_test, output=y_pred)  # tensor
ce = K.eval(g)  # 'ce' for cross-entropy
ce.shape
# (10000,) # i.e. one loss quantity per sample

# sum up and divide with the no. of samples:
log_loss = np.sum(ce)/ce.shape[0]
log_loss
# 0.05165323486328125
```

As you can visually verify, for all practical purposes this is equal to the loss reported by Keras itself above (`score[0]`); indeed:

```
np.isclose(log_loss, score[0])
# True
```

although not *exactly* equal, probably due to numeric precision differences in the two methods:

```
log_loss == score[0]
# False
```

Hopefully, you should now be able use the above procedure to get your log loss between any two sets `y_true` and `y_pred` that are one-hot encoded (like MNIST, that is)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am more interested in the generative modelling task rather than the classification. Basically, I am trying to generate MNIST images pixel by pixel. My model makes a binary prediction for every pixel which can take values of 0 and 1. I think your answer is also valid for this case. The dimension of both logits and labels are [batch_size, 28*28, 1].

Comment: @eaksan could be, but this info should have been explicitly included in your OP; I devoted a non-insignificant amount of time for this answer, and I really hope that at least it will be appreciated accordingly (arguably, I have answered the exact question you asked in your OP)...

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I thought the reference paper could be enough because I was asking how to calculate the numbers in the table I provided.